# Looping throw objects in array for specific returns only one object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects, and Would like to loop through them searching for a specific field, and create a new array that returns objects where that field is equal to what I give it. This works if there's only one object with a field like that, but when there are more, It only returns the first one. I need to return them all

```
const allPosts = [{name:'Post About Health', postCategory:'Health'}, {name:'Post About Money', postCategory:'Money'}, {name:'Post About Health 2', postCategory:'Health'}]

filterPosts('Health')

const filterPosts = (categ) => {
   
    const filterThroughPosts = (category, post) => {
        for (let i=0; i < post.length; i++){
            if(post[i].postCategory === category){

                return [post[i]]
            
            }
            
        }
        
    }

    const returnFilteredPosts = filterThroughPosts(categ, allPosts);
    console.log(returnFilteredPosts) // > Returns only first object where postCategory == health, I need to return both. (Returns [{name:'Post About Health', postCategory:'Health'}]
    //Should return [{name:'Post About Health', postCategory:'Health'}, [{name:'Post About Health 2', postCategory:'Health'}]

}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array.filter()`.

```
const filterPosts = (categ) => {
   
   return allPosts.filter(elm => elm.postCategory === categ);
        
}
filterPosts('Health');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning as soon as you find an object that matches your search criteria, that's why it returns an array with one item in it.
You can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to get your array of objects.